# How to resolve [object ErrorEvent] thrown for karma testing in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

How to solve [object ErrorEvent] thrown, please suggest anyone. When I am writing a test case for specific methods, during the time of debugging method call is going but I am unable to find where [object ErrorEvent] thrown coming.

I am getting like this error

```
Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 19 of 19 (2 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (1 min 7.294 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue and checking the console in my dev tools gave me a lot more info about the error. Throwing in this flag might help too:

```
--source-map=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .means you are telling need to run like this ng test --source-map=false in console

Comment: Yup, that'd be it. But also in your Karma.conf.js set browsers:['Chrome'] and singleRun: false so it'll run in a browser window and you can look at the console error there. Might help.

Answer (score 2):

After my findings, I figure out that we should set `browsers: ['Chrome']` and `singleRun: false` in ***karma.conf.js***. Then run all the test cases and open Chrome browser console and see the error. This way you will reach out the root cause of the problem. This trick worked for me. I hope this trick works for you.

Comment: what is we are using browsers: ['phantomJS'] and error still persist.

Comment: @Irrfan23 phantomJS is good for headless browsers, but for debugging issue you need to change the "browsers" from phantomJS to Chrome for checking the error in console. After watching the error you change it back to phantomJS again!

Comment: the test which is working fine in chrome browser, after chnaging browser to phantomJS its showing error. something different.

Comment: @Irrfan23 What errors does it shows, can u paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the answer from @Dan - but if you're already running the tests you can also use the developer tools Javascript debugger to step through the code to find the issues as well.

I've usually found the error is dereferencing an undefined object in the constructor or ngOnInit method in the component under test.  Either running without source-maps, or debug